# Supporting docker based and non docker based deployments

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, deployment

Currently for my python project I have a deploy.sh file which runs some apt-get's, pip installs, creates some dirs and copies some files.... so the process is git clone my private repo then run deploy.sh.

Now I'm playing with docker, and the basic question is, should the dockerfile RUN a git clone and then RUN deploy.sh or should the dockerfile have its own RUNs for each apt-get, pip, etc and ignore deploy.sh... which seems like duplicating work (typing) and has the possibility of going out of sync?

Answer (score 1):

That work should be duplicated in the dockerfile. The reason for this is to take advantage of docker's layer and caching system. Take this example:

```
# this will only execute the first time you build the image, all future builds will use a cached layer
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install somepackage -y
# this will only run pip if your requirements file changes
ADD requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /app/
```

Also, you should not do a `git checkout` of your code in the docker build. Just simply add the files from the local checkout to the images like in the above example.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, does the pip part of the example still hold true if I'm doing pip install -e .   Or python setup.py install

Comment: @Metalstorm whether or not the `pip` line runs is determined by whether or not the file(s) in the preceding `ADD` line differ from what is in the cache. You can put `-e` inside of a requirements file.

Comment: that is the issue, I don't have a requirement.txt file. All the requirements are under dependancis in setup.py. but then again if I'm ADDing the setup.py and that is different then the pip should run right?

Comment: I would recommend creating one, but you can come up with any system that meets your needs.

Comment: what benifits does it have over the practice I described?